# Kafka on Cloudera - test=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, apache-sentry

We just upgraded from CDH 5.3.6 to 5.10.0, and started getting errors when trying to write to Kafka topics.  We have the default settings on everything, no SSL or Kerberos authentication enabled.  When use the console producer to write to one of my topics, I get this error:

/usr/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list=myhost1.dev.com:9092,myhost2.dev.com:9092 --topic test

```
17/03/06 21:00:57 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.10.0-kafka-2.1.0
17/03/06 21:00:57 INFO utils.AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : unknown
x
17/03/06 21:00:59 WARN clients.NetworkClient: Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 0 : {test=TOPIC_AUTHORIZATION_FAILED}
```

Looking at /var/log/kafka/, I see a bunch of these exceptions:

```
2017-03-06 21:00:26,964 WARN org.apache.sentry.provider.common.HadoopGroupMappingService: Unable to obtain groups for ANONYMOUS
java.io.IOException: No groups found for user ANONYMOUS
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.noGroupsForUser(Groups.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getGroups(Groups.java:210)
    at org.apache.sentry.provider.common.HadoopGroupMappingService.getGroups(HadoopGroupMappingService.java:60)
    at org.apache.sentry.provider.common.ResourceAuthorizationProvider.getGroups(ResourceAuthorizationProvider.java:167)
    at org.apache.sentry.provider.common.ResourceAuthorizationProvider.doHasAccess(ResourceAuthorizationProvider.java:97)
    at org.apache.sentry.provider.common.ResourceAuthorizationProvider.hasAccess(ResourceAuthorizationProvider.java:91)
    at org.apache.sentry.kafka.binding.KafkaAuthBinding.authorize(KafkaAuthBinding.java:212)
    at org.apache.sentry.kafka.authorizer.SentryKafkaAuthorizer.authorize(SentryKafkaAuthorizer.java:63)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis$$anonfun$kafka$server$KafkaApis$$authorize$2.apply(KafkaApis.scala:321)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis$$anonfun$kafka$server$KafkaApis$$authorize$2.apply(KafkaApis.scala:321)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.kafka$server$KafkaApis$$authorize(KafkaApis.scala:321)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis$$anonfun$30.apply(KafkaApis.scala:702)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis$$anonfun$30.apply(KafkaApis.scala:702)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$partition$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:314)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$partition$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:314)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:94)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.partition(TraversableLike.scala:314)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.partition(Traversable.scala:104)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleTopicMetadataRequest(KafkaApis.scala:702)
    at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:79)
    at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:60)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've been looking for a solution to this, but have come up empty so far.  Do I need to assign the ANONYMOUS user to some groups somewhere?  I was able to write messages to my topics in CDH 5.3.6, but it appears something has gone wrong in the upgrade.

Just trying to get the helloWorld/Quickstart example to work again on our DEV Kafka after upgrading to CDH 5.10.0.

----------------- Temporary workaround solution ---

In cloudera manager 5.10 there is a super.users property in the kafka configuration.  Adding ANONYMOUS to that list, allowed me to produce and consume from my topics.

I had already tried doing this in /opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA-2.1.0-1.2.1.0.p0.115/etc/kafka/conf.dist/server.properties, which had no effect.  So Cloudera must be managing these values elsewhere.

Comment: Can you check the value you have set for _authorizer.class.name_ please? When you don't have Kerberos or SSL configured you can still enforce ACLs if something is set here, everybody connecting will be authenticated as "ANONYMOUS" though, which is what you can see in your log.

Comment: I modified /opt/cloudera/parcels/KAFKA-2.1.0-1.2.1.0.p0.115/etc/kafka/conf.dist/server.properties to have this line:  authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer  But it didn't seem to matter and I wasn't even sure if that was the right file, or how to verify the change took effect.

Comment: Yep, that lire is what's causing this (not sure about the file, but seems to fit). With that line you tell Kafka to apply ACLs to all connect attempts - all of which will be against "ANONYMOUS". I'd recommend removing that line and everything should work. Alternatively you can set ANONYMOUS as superuser in the config which should have the same effect, but doesn't offer any additional security, so is not really useful imo.

Comment: Sadly, this error started happening before I added that line, right after upgrade.  I have since removed it and its still happening.  Could it be configured somewhere else besides that server.properties file?  I don't see it anywhere in the Cloudera Manager.

Comment: Hi medloh - if you are stuck you can try out http://www.landoop.com/devops/kafka-on-cloudera/

Comment: Not sure whether the setting is in CM, I don't have a cluster at hand to check. I think there is an option to add superusers somewhere, if that is enabled without checking Kerberos authentication maybe try adding anonymous there as a workaround.

Comment: I found the superusers setting in Cloudera Kafka config. Adding ANONYMOUS to it let me produce and consume messages. Although we'd have to find a better solution when we get to production someday.   Sonke, if you want some rep, write up an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka strictly distinguishes between authentication and authorization - even if you have authentication via Kerb or SSL turned of it is still possible to turn authorization on via the following parameter:

```
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorize‌​r
```

This will make Kafka check ACLs for every access - since authentication is turned of in your case though, every user will be evaluated as *ANONYMOUS* and denied, if there are no ACLs set for this user.

You can delete that setting from your config which should make Kafka return to its old, trusting, self. I am not sure where you'd do this in Cloudera Manager though, so an alternative would be to add *ANONYMOUS* to the list of super users which is available in CM. Or of course just define an ACL to allow access to *ANONYMOUS*.

For production use later on you should probably set up either SSL or Kerberos and define proper ACLs if there is any chance of the cluster being accessed from the outside.